# pycharm failing to load module included in the list of interpreter paths

Tags: pycharm, pythonpath

I'm a bit lost here. Modules `specrefl.resolution` and `specrefl.model` fail to import in my `test_model.py` script even though I included the path to package `specrefl` in the list of interpreter paths (it's the last line in the list).

Can anyone please indicate what could I be missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved after I:

- closed the project
- deleted the .idea/ folder
- updated pycharm (probably not necessary)
- restarted pycharm
- reloaded the project